# Oracle sava clob from utf8 to file WE8ISO8859P1

Tags: oracle

I'm generating a clob memory. I want to save it on my hard drive in WE8ISO8859P1 (8 bit) encryption, it doesn't work... ;) I tried everything

```
create or replace PROCEDURE A1 AS 
  c clob;
  b blob;
  lDestOffset integer := 1;
  lSrcOffset integer := 1;
  lWarning integer := 0;
  lLangContext INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
  lAmount integer;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(c, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION); 
  for x in 1..1000
  loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(c, 10, 'ĄćĄćĄćĄćĄć');
  end loop;

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(b, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);
  DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(b, c, length(c), lDestOffset, lSrcOffset, nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1'), lLangContext, lWarning);

  dbms_output.put_line('Source CLOB UTF8:');
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(c, 100, 1));
  dbms_output.put_line('Dest BLOB WE8ISO8859P1:');
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(b, 100, 1));

  /*l_conn := ftp.login('X.X.X.X', 21, 'etykiety', 'ASDFASDFASDFASDF');
  FTP.BINARY(p_conn => l_conn);    

  FTP.PUT_REMOTE_BINARY_DATA(l_conn, 'TEST.TXT', b);

  ftp.logout(l_conn);*/
END A1;

Source CLOB UTF8:
ĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄćĄć
Dest BLOB WE8ISO8859P1:
BFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBF
```

Comment: Character `Ą` and `ć` are not defined in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), thus you cannot store them and they are replaced by placeholder `¿`

Comment: OMG:) It's possible.)

Comment: Perhaps you got me wrong: You cannot put `Ą` or `ć` in a ISO 8859-1 file - NEVER. In case you have a different opinion: Which byte values would you expect to represent `Ą` or `ć`? However, it should work with ISO-8859-2 (EE8ISO8859P2),  ISO-8859-16 (n/a in Oracle), ISO-8859-13 (BLT8ISO8859P13)